# Best Way to load images

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I am creating a mobile app and realized that the logout is displayed before the images are loaded. (And it takes a little while to load one image) I can see this being a issue when I add more.

**Are there any recommendations on how I could load my images efficiently instead of bottle necking it ? OR how can I just implement a way for a loading screen to show until all images are loaded**

```
<!-- end wrapper div -->
        <div ng-repeat="i in data" class='wrapper'>
            <!-- wrapper div -->
            <!-- add address of information here!!!! -->


            <!-- image -->
            <a href="#/nextPage">
                <img style="float:left; display:inline-block;overflow:hidden; border: 1px;" class="fill_image" src='{{ i.picture }}' style
                    width="100%" style height="100%" ng-click="disableClick('{{ i.firebase_url }}')"/>
            </a>

            <!-- description div -->
            <div class='description'>
                <!-- description content -->
                <p class='name' style="float: left">{{ i.title }}</p>
                <p class='name' style="float: right">Free</p>


                <!-- end description content -->
            </div>
            <!-- end description div -->

        </div>

        <button ng-click="logOut()" class="button button-clear button-positive">Logout</button>
```

Javascript file:

```
'Use Strict';
angular.module('App').controller('homeController', function ($scope, $state, $cordovaOauth, $localStorage, $firebaseArray, $location, $http, $ionicPopup, $firebaseObject, Auth, FURL, Utils, $ionicHistory) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FURL);
    $scope.product;

    // Get a reference to our posts
    var ref = new Firebase("https://<database>/properties");

    $scope.data = $firebaseArray(ref);


    $scope.disableClick = function (n) {
        localStorage.setItem('labelz', n);

    }


    $scope.logOut = function () {
        Auth.logout();
        $location.path("/login");
    }

        $scope.goBack = function () {
        $ionicHistory.goBack();
    }

}
);
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you have a typo in your strict mode directive. It needs to be `'use strict'`, not `'Use Strict'`.

Comment: Thank you. Also is there a reason why I am getting marked down on this post?

Comment: While you *can* store images in Firebase, it's really not ideal for image storage. If they are tiny - 32x32 pixels for example, not a big deal, but its not a recommended (by Firebase) practice. You are much better off leveraging another storage company for the actual storage and store the links to those images in Firebase. I didn't mark it down, but if you do a search on Firebase and Image Storage - you'll see there are numerous posts recommended against it.

Comment: What's in `i.picture`?

Comment: i.picture is just the url of the image

Comment: Ok...so I guess I see the issue in asking this question. Seems too broad. I was hoping there was someway to load the pictures efficiently like instagram or facebook. Does anyone know the best way to implement a loading screen in this case. I have a loading screen (Utils.show is the call for it and Util.hide hides it); What would be the best way to implement it in this case

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for ngCloak directive. more info here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak